# PHP how to pipe a variable to netcat with shell_exec

Tags: php, pipe

I want to send the content of a string (labeldata for barcode printer) to netcat for printing. I get it to work by writing the string to a file and using the code below.

```
$file = 'out.prn';
file_put_contents($file, $normal_label);
$prn_status = shell_exec('cat '.$file.' | netcat -w 1 192.168.31.10 8000');
```

but how can I do it directly from the variable? I've tried different things like

```
shell_exec($normal_label > netcat...
shell_exec($normal_label | netcat...
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `'cat '.$file.'` to `'echo '.$file.'`

Comment: I think @NigelRen meant changing `'cat '.$file.'` to `'echo '.$normal_label.'`

Comment: Anyway, why don't you write directly to 192.168.31.10:8000 with [fsockopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php) instead of using `netcat` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you script to work, you may change this line:

```php
$prn_status = shell_exec('cat '.$file.' | netcat -w 1 192.168.31.10 8000');
```

to this:

```php
$prn_status = shell_exec('echo '.$normal_label.' | netcat -w 1 192.168.31.10 8000');
```

But, instead of depending on netcat, you may also write to the TCP port directly with [fsockopen](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php). Then you script would also work on system that do not have `netcat` on it. More portable (yay):

```php
<?php

$fp = fsockopen('192.168.31.10', 8000, $errno, $errstr, 30);

if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $result = '';
    fwrite($fp, $normal_label);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $result .= fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: Ok, fsockopen looks like a good idea but for the moment something happens with the content as the printer does not accept it (goes into error mode because of error in data). My example works (with file_puts_content), what I actually was looking for was a way to send the string directly without the need to write it to file first.

Comment: I suggest you to try to add an EOL mark (`"\n"`)  at the end of your `$normal_label`  to see if it works. Perhaps the printer it.

Comment: It was actually a typo that made the printer stop, but the real problem was the while loop as the printer does not output a eof and php gets stuck until the timeout. I removed it and only used the fgets with 7 chars as that is always the return length and now it works perfectly. Thanks!